# does a purely real FFT algorithm exist?

Tags: fft

I am perfectly aware that you can efficiently use the standard FFT Cooley Tuckey algorithm to process N samples with one complex N/2 sized FFT. This however requires one additional loop before the FFT to "prepare" the data and one after to rearrange them.
I am rather wondering whether a natively real FFT implementation existed, working on a sequence of N samples directly and returning a half complex spectrum directly i.e N/2+1 bins (which still sums to N floats since DC and Nyquist have null imaginaries). Does such a natively real FFT algorithm exist ?
Standing to my experiments and calculations  it can be done in theory, since it is still about recursively split data in half, computing the FFT and combine, but the actual implementation if one wants to keep efficiency high and avoid recursion and copy operations can be very hard and puzzling, that's why I asked whether there was something similar already. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you define "native" and "FFT"?. You can certainly write a DFT algorithm for real input, but it wouldn't be very fast.

Comment: Maybe the Discrete Hartley Transform (DHT) and FHT is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the implementation of `rfft` in the FFTW library. Also, I second Andy's suggestion to look at the Hartley transform.

Comment: Are you asking if there is an algorithm for calculating a real FFT that has less arithmetic complexity than a state-of-the-art N/2 complex FFT with pre or post processing? I don't know, interesting question. Or are you asking what is the fastest known way to calculate a real FFT on your computer? The answer to that is probably "FFTW" :-)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will have a look at fftw and Hartley transform. However yes I was wondering whether a more efficient form of the N/2 with pre and post processing version existed, since from my experiments it turns out you can indeed compute a FFT by progressively creating double sized half complex spectra, but the matter is to efficiently implement it

Comment: This looks like it might be promising if someone what's to turn it into an answer: [REAL FFT ALGORITHMS](http://www.robinscheibler.org/2013/02/13/real-fft.html)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the the blog entry [REAL FFT ALGORITHMS](http://www.robinscheibler.org/2013/02/13/real-fft.html).

I strongly recommend taking the advice from this blog entry:

> Nevertheless, don’t try to implement these algorithms, except for
> educational purpose. If you need to use these algorithms in practice,
> very efficient implementations, such as FFTW, already exists.

The real to complex, special case FFT, is available from the Fastest Fourier Transform in the West ([FFTW](https://www.fftw.org)) package and documented as [One-Dimensional DFTs of Real Data](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html) (`fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`).

Assumptions: the input sequence $x[x]$ is real, indexed from $n=0$ to $n=N-1$ where $N$ is even.

1. Start with decimation in time ($j$ is the imaginary unit):
   $$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}}$$
   $$= \sum_{n_1=0}^{N/2-1} x[2n_1]e^{-j2\pi\frac{k(2n_1)}{N}} + \sum_{n_2=0}^{N/2-1} x[2n_2+1]e^{-j2\pi\frac{k(2n_2+1)}{N}}$$
   $$= \sum_{n_1=0}^{N/2-1} x[2n_1]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn_1}{N/2}} + \sum_{n_2=0}^{N/2-1} x[2n_2+1]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn_2}{N/2}}$$
   $$=X_e[k]+X_o[k]e^{-j2\pi\frac{k}{N}}$$
   where $X_e[k]$ is the Fourier transform of the even portion of the input signal $x_e[n] = x[2n]$ and $X_o[k]$ is the Fourier transform of the off portion $x_o[n] = x[2n+1]$.
2. Use the "two-for-one" method to compute $X_e[k]$ and $X_o[k]$ using a single $N/2$ point complex FFT.
3. Let $z[m] = x_e[m] + jx_o[m]$
4. $\DeclareMathOperator{\FFT}{FFT} Z[n] = \FFT^{N/2}_m\{z[m]\}$
5. $X_e[k] = \frac{Z[k]+Z^*[N/2-k]}{2}$ where the superscript $*$ indicates the complex conjugate
6. $X_o[k] = -j\frac{Z[k]-Z^*[N/2-k]}{2}$
7. The desired solution is then:
   $$X[k] = X_e[k\bmod N/2] + X_o[k \bmod N/2]e^{-j2\pi\frac{k}{N}}$$
   where $k=0, \cdots, N-1$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying my own question, in the end I had to code my own real transforms:
http://www.elenadomain.it/listing/SE/ElenaRFFT.c
I have no intentions to benchmark it and I don't want to declare they are better or worse than what it is already available. I can just limit to say that it is a very compact and optimized code, simple to use, and it tries to use the least number of operations and memory accesses needed, and from my test it results 30-40% faster than using a complex fft to process a real sequence and rearraging the result in a half complex spectrum. I am posting this simply in case this code may turn out useful to somebody else